# Failed to configure Remote Desktop for cloud service

Tags: azure

I've been trying to configure the remote access on my Azure cloud service instances. I've tried it through redeploying the project and also directly on the management console, I've tried it with existing certificates and by creating a new one but it always fails with an error message like:

> The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request. The long running operation tracking ID was: 3a692c5fd4fb4d2caca013796daa2fa1.

Help, anyone!?

Comment: When are you getting this message - when deploying a certificate or connecting to a RDP session?

Comment: Everytime I've seen this it seems to fix itself.  Seems to be related to the data center, you could try switching to a data center in another location and try again...

Comment: @SliverNinja, from what I know, one can configure the remote desktop on the visual studio project and then deploy the package on Azure or on can configure it directly on the Azure using the Management portal. Both approaches end on the above stated error message, so I never get passed the configuration part. And in order to be able to deploy my project again without I'm forced to remove the option for allowing remote desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this kind of error message few months ago.
my problem was

```
 1.Certificate for RDP is not matching(thumb print) with the certificates uploaded in the portal
 2.matching Certificates but the Account is expired  change the expire date
 3.Check the Activate Windows Azure connect and the activation token on config of worker role
 4.While **decreasing the instance size say Medium Vm to SmallVm**, delete and recreate to avoid this kind of error message.
```

Answer (score 0):

RDP port (3389) is widely blocked from network administrators of most corporations. What you need to do is either of:

- Talking with your network administrator at work and ask for
  permission to use RDP port to connect to your Azure Virtual Machine
- Configure different public port for the RDP Endpoint. Setting it to
  443 (the HTTPS Standard port) or 22 (Standard SSH port) might solve
  the issue without contacting system administrator

Of course, if you use that VM for Secure Web (which works on 443) you have to chose another port number.

Reference: [Windows Azure VM Remote desktop connection issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324041/windows-azure-vm-remote-desktop-connection-issue)