# Windows Azure VM Remote desktop connection issue

Tags: windows, azure

I created a windows azure VM with Windows server 2008 R2. The status of the server  is running. The port is open.  But I cannot RDP to it. It gives me an error

> Remote Desktop can’t connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:
>
> 1. Remote access to the server is not enabled
> 2. The remote computer is turned off
> 3. The remote computer is not available on the network
>
> Make sure the remote computer is turned on and connected to the network, and that remote access is enabled.

Any help ? I actually created twice but no luck

**EDIT**

I am able to connect from home. but not from work network. so definitely a work network restrictions. Could you suggest what should be my next step to make it accessible from work

Comment: Did you download the "rdp" file from your Windows Azure account? That will populate all the credentials and address.

Comment: Yes I did. I even tried to edit it with IP address in that . same error.

Comment: Can you ping it? Try to disable your firewall/antivirus

Comment: I cant ping. It times out. I think I dont have the privilege to disable firewall/antivirus

Comment: I am able to connect from home. but not from work network. so definitely a work network restrictions.  Could you suggest what should be my next step to make it accessible from work.

Comment: @Jaleel - Since this is related to your work network, please resolve this question by posting that as your answer. You'll need to talk to your network admin about opening outbound RDP (port 3389), and helping you diagnose things beyond that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

RDP port (3389) is widely blocked from network administrators of most corporations. What you need to do is either of:

- Talking with your network administrator at work and ask for permission to use RDP port to connect to your Azure Virtual Machine
- Configure different [**public port** for the RDP Endpoint](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/setup-endpoints/). Setting it to 443 (the HTTPS Standard port) or 22 (Standard SSH port) might solve the issue without contacting system administrator

Of course, if you use that VM for Secure Web (which works on 443) you have to chose another port number.

Comment: thanks for the answer.When i look at VM machine , I can see I have two ports available. 3389 as private port and another public  one xxxx too. Do I need to ask network admin to open both?

Comment: hi, one more question, the network admin is pushing back saying that this is a matter of security vulnerability for the on-premise network. Is it really so? thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: whether or not to open outgoing port is sole personal opinion and I will not comment on that. So you just need to change the public port and you are done. You can set it to even 80 (given you will not be running WEB loads on that machine that will need public port 80)

Comment: This eventually worked for me. I'll add that you may need to restart the VM from the azure portal before the new port mapping will take effect.

Comment: What about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049304/windows-azure-rdp-port-forwarding-not-working

Comment: @AsifAshraf not relevant since in the original question here there is only **one** VM deployed! Also, please note question's and answer's dates!

Comment: Same problem. I changed the public port to 443 for RDP and that worked. My assumption is that the random 5000+ port that azure picked was blocked by work network.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

After I did "Reset Remote", "Reset VM", Initially the Public and Private Port was different as expected, I changed both Public & Private to "3389" and then Edited the RDP File (which was originally downloaded from Azure) to have my UserID on it, then it worked. (Didn't bother on security as it is for a short session)

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. Have followed the Below steps and it got resolved.

1. Changed the both port number to 3389.
2. After changing, Restarted the  VM once.
3. On Restart, reset the Password with new credential.
4. Clicked on connect and downloaded the RDP file.
5. Executed the file  and provided the User name and Credential.

Hope this helps to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case it's the proxy settings. I changed it form my chrome browser settings

Settings -> show advanced settings -> Change Proxy settings -> LAN settings

and than enabling the proxy settings & Bypass proxy server for local addresses

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share what worked for me.

After receiving an error prompt:

> Connect is disabled for this virtual machine because of the following
>   issues: Network interface 'vmwindows1094': Network security group
>   'VMWindows10-nsg' does not have inbound security rule that allows port
>   3389. VMWindows10-nsg

I have added an inbound port rule. Under `VM > Settings > Add inbound port rules.`

```
Port: 3389
Protocol/Source/Destination: Any (this can be configured based on your security rules)
Action: Allow
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me. My friend at work figured it out.

1) In Azure, Create a Load Balancer.

- Accept the defaults but put your VM's public IP Address to the Public IP Address name.

2) Inside the Load Balancer > Go to Inbound NAT rules
Use HTTP, Port 80, Single Virtual Machine, Target your VM, Target Port is 3389.

I don't know the underlying principles on how it works but it does.
Thank you Mr. Arturo Tiangco

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I did the following to resolve it:

- Login via serial console (instructions below).
- At the command prompt, within the guest vm:
  `ipconfig /renew`
- Log in into serial, type `cmd` and enter
- Type `ch -si 1` and then enter.
- Log in using the domain admin account or local admin account
- Enter `ipconfig /release`

Answer (score -1):

## Problem

An error message displays in the management portal for tenants when accessing a virtual machine using RDP (Connect->Desktop on the command bar), that Remote desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:

- The access to the server is not enabled.
- The remote server is turned off.
- The remote computer is not available on the network.

## Recommendation

You may need to include the public profile in the setting that allows Remote Desktop through the virtual machine's firewall. You will need to adjust the firewall setting in the Control Panel of the tenant's virtual machine using Virtual Machine Manager. Perform the following procedure:

- In Virtual Machine Manager on the VMs and Services tab, find the cloud that is hosting the tenant's virtual machine, and select that virtual machine.
- On the ribbon, click Connect or View->Connect via Desktop.
- Sign on with the computer's Administrator password the tenant set when the virtual machine was created.
- In Control Panel, click System  and Security->Windows Firewall->Allow an App or Feature through Windows Firewall.
- Scroll down to Remote Desktop and make sure the Public profile is checked. By default it is not.

Comment: I didn't get step no 1. can you elaborate? Where do I find Virtaul Machine Manger?