# Cannot connect to Azure VMs after restart

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, iaas

I'm trying to configure a couple of virtual machines using Windows Azure. To save costs I shut down the VMs at the end of each day and start them the next morning.

However, after coming back to work and starting all my VMS I don't have remote desktop access to my machines anymore. First I got an error mentioning NLA:

> The remote computer requires Network Level Authentication, which your
>   computer does not support. For assistance, contact your system
>   administrator or technical support.

I then deleted the VMs and recreated them from the existing disk. Now I simply get the following the error:

> Remote Desktop can’t connect to the remote computer for one
>   of these reasons:
>
> 1) Remote access to the server is not enabled 2) The remote computer
>   is turned off 3) The remote computer is not available on the network
>
> Make sure the remote computer is turned on and connected to the
>   network, and that remote access is enabled.

Remote access was enabled before shutting down the machines. I can't check the settings for remote desktop because I can't access the machines.

What should I do?

Comment: You should take look at this answer : [Windows Azure VM remote desktop connection issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324041/windows-azure-vm-remote-desktop-connection-issue). If you try to connect at work this might be helpful.

Comment: What type of configurations you performed on the VMs? Because what you are experiencing is not the usual way how Azure behaves.

Comment: I've tried changing the public port numbers for the RD endpoint. I've also disabled the firewall at my pc and my router. I still can't connect.

Comment: I'm configuring a Team Foundation Server environment. I've configured one VM as AD Domain Controller and joined the other vms to the domain. Strange thing is I can connect to some machines (a VM with SQL Server for example) but not to another VM (one still empty server and the domain controller)

Answer (score 1):

If you have powershell remote access, try to connect with it and check with Get-NetFirewallRule if anything changed on this.

You can use [IaaS Management Studio](http://iaas.ao-is.com/), if you don't want to bother using powershell.
You can also check if the open port are responding in the endpoint windows.

At worse, just delete the vm and recreate it. (You can copy the vhd else where, and create a second vm if you are afraid of losing what you did)

I had cases of hack on my VMs when I used obvious login/password on obvious RDP port... might be your case too.