# Azure VM and remote control issue

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machine, remote-access

I can't get access to Azure VM. Although the button "Connect" in Azure Manager is active, I can't get the remote access (TCP input) because of the error:

> Remote Desktop can’t connect to the remote computer for one of these
>   reasons:
>
> ```
> Remote access to the server is not enabled
> The remote computer is turned off
> The remote computer is not available on the network
> ```
>
> Make sure the remote computer is turned on and connected to the
>   network, and that remote access is enabled.

I've tried many things, such as adding ports 443, 22 (which, as claimed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324041/windows-azure-vm-remote-desktop-connection-issue), may work) and disabling an antivirus (Avira) and Windows Brandmauer (as well as checking if operation Remote control (TCP input) is allowed in inbound rules of brandmauer). My remote OS is Windows 8, while the VM is Ubuntu 15.10.

How to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**There is all the things you should check when having RDP issues in Azure**, from the most common to the least :

1. Reset Remote Desktop service from the Azure portal to fix startup
   issues with the RDP server. Click Browse > Virtual machines
   (classic) > your Windows virtual machine > Reset Remote....
2. Restart the Virtual Machine to address other startup issues. Click
   Browse > Virtual machines (classic) > your Windows virtual machine >
   Restart.
3. Resize the VM to fix any host issues. Click Browse > Virtual
   machines (classic) > your Windows virtual machine > Settings > Size.
   For detailed steps, see Resize the virtual machine.
4. Review your VM’s console log or screenshot to correct boot problems.
   Click Browse > Virtual machines (classic) > your Windows virtual
   machine > Settings > Boot diagnostics.
5. Check VM's Resource Health for any platform issues. Click Browse >
   Virtual machines (classic) > your Windows virtual machine > Settings

   > Check Health.

*I've got this problem some time ago, the solution was simply to reset the remote access.*